# SQL - Slight error in query that counts from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have a query that needs a little tweaking. It counts perfectly well when I count The Brands that are associated with the Sites, but when I try to count the Models that are associated with the brands, the number of sites changes.

The tables are

```
SITES
SiteID // pk
SiteName

BRANDS
BrandID // pk
SiteID // fk
Brand

MODELS
ModelID // pk
BrandID // fk
```

This query yields the correct number of TotalBrands associated with a site:

```
        SELECT      S.SiteID,
                    S.SiteName,
                    COUNT(B.BrandID) AS TotalBrands
        FROM        Sites S
                    LEFT JOIN Brands B
                        ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
        GROUP BY    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
```

When I add a little bit more to the query, the TotalBrands is inaccurate.

```
        SELECT      S.SiteID,
                    S.SiteName,
                    COUNT(B.BrandID) AS TotalBrands,
                    COUNT(M.ModelID) AS TotalModels
        FROM        Sites S
                    LEFT JOIN Brands B
                        ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
                    LEFT JOIN Models M
                        ON B.BrandID = M.BrandID
        GROUP BY    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
```

I want to include all sites, whether they have Brands or not. I want to count all Brands whether they have Models or not.  I want to count all Models.

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: If a Brand can have more than one model associated with it, you'd end up counting that Brand once for each model. Perhaps using `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` would be more appropriate?

Comment: Your query will (FOR EACH Site, FOR EACH BRAND, get the number of models). So if you have A sites, B brands and C models, you'll get A*B*C results.

Comment: Can you modify my code to give me an example of how DISTINCT would be used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was said in the comments, you are multipliying results on your last `JOIN`. So you etiher do a `DISTINCT` count, or do the grouping before.

```
SELECT      S.SiteID,
            S.SiteName,
            COUNT(B.BrandID) AS TotalBrands,
            SUM(M.Models) AS TotalModels
FROM        Sites S
            LEFT JOIN Brands B
                ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT BrandId, COUNT(*) Models 
                        FROM Models
                        GROUP BY BrandId) M
                ON B.BrandID = M.BrandID
GROUP BY    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
```

Or

```
SELECT      S.SiteID,
            S.SiteName,
            COUNT(DISTINCT B.BrandID) AS TotalBrands,
            COUNT(M.ModelId) AS TotalModels
FROM        Sites S
            LEFT JOIN Brands B
                ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
            LEFT JOIN Models M
                ON B.BrandID = M.BrandID
GROUP BY    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
```

Comment: +1 imho this is the preferred solution against DISTINCT. DISTINCT is too often just added "to filter out extra results so it works", this is the real structural solution.